# Draw a line between points to compare, plot and analyze using python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, opencv

[image: Sample image to be processed]

I wanted to draw a line in every point between the white spot and the green rectangle-like beside each spot (the green ones served as the reference and the spots are the distorted ones which I would like to get the difference between them and plot it (surface plot,etc..)

Also, I used this code to detect the spots:

```
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0,:].astype("int"))
    for (x,y,r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(output2, (x,y),r,(0,255,0),2)
```

[image: Sample image with detected spots]

how can I know the center of each spot and how to use them as an array/list? just to begin with, because based on what I read, these are necessary to plot the shape. Thanks

Comment: Which aspect are you stuck with? Do you not know the coordinates of the centres of the white dots? Or do you not know how to draw a line? Or something else?

Comment: @MarkSetchell ok sorry for that, I'm just new here. I already edited my post. thanks

Comment: @MarkSetchell going back to my queries, i rly need some help. thankss

Comment: @bad_apple you can you Hough transform for circle detection of a fixed radius

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `scikit-image` Hough-transform. Using the following code you can detect the circles, find the centers and radii (you can use `cv2`'s corresponding functions in the same way):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import data, color, io
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte

image = color.rgb2gray(img_as_ubyte(io.imread('new images/FjOll.png')))
edges = canny(image, sigma=1)
hough_radii = [6] # detect circles of radius 6
hough_res = hough_circle(edges, hough_radii)
# select most prominent 25 circles
accums, cx, cy, radii = hough_circle_peaks(hough_res, hough_radii, total_num_peaks=20)
# Draw circles
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1, figsize=(10, 4))
image = color.gray2rgb(image)
for center_y, center_x, radius in zip(cy, cx, radii):
    circy, circx = circle_perimeter(center_y, center_x, radius)
    print(center_y, center_x, radius)
    image[circy, circx] = (255, 0, 0)
ax.imshow(image)
plt.show()
## detected circles: (center_y, center_x, radius)
# (171, 103, 6)
# (56, 38, 6)
# (16, 99, 6)
# (141, 128, 6)
# (126, 32, 6)
# (95, 159, 6)
# (120, 90, 6)
# (56, 96, 6)
# (57, 157, 6)
# (120, 158, 6)
# (140, 62, 6)
# (108, 64, 6)
# (77, 64, 6)
# (42, 68, 6)
# (106, 130, 6)
# (73, 128, 6)
# (38, 127, 6)
# (75, 130, 6)
# (88, 38, 6)
# (86, 93, 6)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I draw a line between each corresponding spots and their reference? For example, one spot being displaced to the reference point which is the square beside it.In which, after drawing a line between each of them, I need to calculate their displacements.

Comment: I am assuming that you already know the coordinates (x,y) of the reference squares and now the above code gives you the coordinates (x',y') of the corresponding spots. The euclidean distance is just sqrt((x-x')^2+(y-y')^2)